Can a NN reproduce differentiation while computing?
Gradients especcialy usefull in computer vision, when we need to find edges, corners, contours. But algorithms for finding edges, corners, contours, intersections (canny, harris ...) are very sensitive to tuning. If the algorithm is good for one frame, it doesn't have to be good for the another frame.
So, what if we can train a NN for edge, corner... detection? Intensity gradient at the each pixel is the key point to detect.
So, can a NN reproduce differentiation for each pixel of the image?
